# How to remove duplicate values of only one column element based on another column

Tags: r, data.table

I have data where I have one element of interest (111) in a column. My data looks something like this:

```
pcp2 <- data.frame(A = c(rep(111, 4), rep(222, 5), rep(111,5), 
        rep(222,5)),B= c(rep(1,9), rep(2,10))) 

     A  B
1   111 1
2   111 1
3   111 1
4   111 1
5   222 1
6   222 1
7   222 1
8   222 1
9   222 1
10  111 2
11  111 2
12  111 2
13  111 2
14  111 2
15  222 2
16  222 2
17  222 2
18  222 2
19  222 2
```

I want to collapse all of only variable 222 and leave all 111 untouched throughout my data based upon the IDs in column B like so:

```
     A  B
1   111 1
2   111 1
3   111 1
4   111 1
5   222 1
6   111 2
7   111 2
8   111 2
9   111 2
10  111 2
11  222 2
```

All I have been able to find that is close reduces all the variables (both 111 and 222).

```
library(data.table)
dat <- as.data.table(pcp2, key = "B")
data <- dat[, by = key(dat)][!duplicated(A == "222")]
```

as follows:

```
   A    B
1 111   1
2 222   2
```

I've played around with various iterations of this code and others, but other things I've tried as well have just gotten my data down to two rows or collapsed both 111 and 222. I.e. this wouldn't be sufficient:

```
   A  B
1 111 1
2 222 2
3 111 2
4 222 2
```

Does anyone have any guidance for how you would maintain the 111 and collapse the 222 within one column based on another column like the example (B in this case)? I know other examples are similar but none seem to give the option to specify not collapsing a particular variable within one column while collapsing the other(s).

Comment: if you change `pcp2[7, 2] = 2` - do you expect to get 3 rows with `A = 222` at the end, or just 2?

Comment: Just 2. I would expect one value of 222 PER each unique identifier in column B, no more though. So for this one 222 for when column B is 1 and one 222 for when column B is 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution using `slice`. This solution *does not* assume that the other values of `A` other than `111` are `222`:

```
library(dplyr)

pcp2 %>%
  group_by(B, A) %>%
  slice(if(any(A == "111")) 1:n() else 1)
```

Alternatively using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(pcp2)[, .I[if(any(A=="111")) 1:.N else 1], by = c("B", "A")][,.SD, .SDcols = A:B]
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 12 x 2
# Groups:   B, A [5]
       A     B
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1   111     1
 2   111     1
 3   111     1
 4   111     1
 5   222     1
 6   111     2
 7   111     2
 8   111     2
 9   111     2
10   111     2
11   222     2
12   333     2

      A B
 1: 111 1
 2: 111 1
 3: 111 1
 4: 111 1
 5: 222 1
 6: 111 2
 7: 111 2
 8: 111 2
 9: 111 2
10: 111 2
11: 222 2
12: 333 2
```

**Data:**

```
pcp2 <- data.frame(A = c(rep(111, 4), rep(222, 5), rep(111,5), 
                         rep(222,5), rep(333, 5)), B= c(rep(1,9), rep(2,10), rep(2, 5)))
```

Comment: Fyi, you can do `row_number()` instead of `1:n()`

Comment: @Frank Sure, but it seems that `1:n()` is less typing :p

Answer (score 3):

You can add a counter for the uncollapsed rows:

```
dat[, r := rowid(A)*(A == 111)]
unique(dat, by=c("B","r"))[, !"r"]

      A B
 1: 111 1
 2: 111 1
 3: 111 1
 4: 111 1
 5: 222 1
 6: 111 2
 7: 111 2
 8: 111 2
 9: 111 2
10: 111 2
11: 222 2
```

(This requires data.table, while Gregor's answer works in base R as well.)

Answer (score 2):

I would phrase your goal as "keep rows that are not duplicated or where A is 111", with the understanding that `duplicated` is FALSE for the first occurrence.

`duplicated(pcp2)` looks at all columns, so we don't need to worry about the "within each B group" stuff. If you have other columns hanging around, only give `duplicated` the relevant columns, something like `duplicated(pcp2[c("A", "B")])`.

```
pcp2[!duplicated(pcp2) | pcp2$A == 111, ]
#      A B
# 1  111 1
# 2  111 1
# 3  111 1
# 4  111 1
# 5  222 1
# 10 111 2
# 11 111 2
# 12 111 2
# 13 111 2
# 14 111 2
# 15 222 2
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! The only issue I have when I run this is that it's missing the 222 from unique ID 2 in column B...(#15 222 2)

Comment: When I first posted the code, I did `duplicated(pcp2$A)`, which only looked at the A column. I realized the mistake and corrected to `duplicated(pcp2)` which fixes that problem.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm not sure why but when I applied this to my actual data it didn't work and only collapsed some of the values I wanted collapsed. It did work when I tried it on my sample above though. Perhaps I should have mentioned that I have actual text not integers? I placed those in quotes but was still unsuccessful. Still trying to figure out what it actually did so I can provide more details but it took about 200/6000 rows.

Comment: If you have other columns in your data, see my note about using `duplicated(pcp2[c("A", "B")])`.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much, it just clicked. Ran it again and worked perfectly. Appreciate it!